# How get value from aggregations in Elasticsearch dsl

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I began to understand with Elasticsearch dsl and faced with problem. I can not get value from aggregations. I is use the metric method, but is get a error, when I want to get the value from 'new_distance'. What doing wrong?

```
    res = MyIndex.search()\
      .filter('geo_distance', distance='1km', location={"lat":"32.895", "lon":"21.115"})\
      .aggs.metric('new_distance', 'max', field='point')
    result = res.to_queryset()
    print(result[0].new_distance)
```

error

```
'Comments' object has no attribute 'new_distance'
```

Comment: When you call `to_queryset()` you get back a regular Django queryset. It is no longer a `Response` object and so you cannot access any aggregations that were returned by Elasticsearch. If you want to use the aggregations then you need to work with the result object without converting to a queryset.

Comment: Thanks, how can you disperse the dsl object?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "disperse"?